# Setting up a label custom control ?

Tags: ios, uilabel

I need to set up a label control code by hand, I have this:

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
[label setText: @"My Label"];
[label setTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
```

but after running this code, the label is not showing....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed one line of code `[self.view addSubview: label];` code should be write like

```
UILabel* label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: labelFrame];
[label setText: @"My Label"];
[label setTextColor: [UIColor orangeColor]];
[self.view addSubview: label]
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it as a subview to an existing view.

```
[self.view addSubview:label];
```